# Android - Custom SeekBar - Unnecessary white space on bottom of the seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I need to customize a seekbar. To achieve this I'm using a `layer-list` XML file, and then set it as background to seekbar.
For the `@android:id/background` I'm using a bitmap, for `secondaryProgress` and `progress`, I'm using a shape.
This is the XML background file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/progressbar_bg"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />

    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#B2B2B2" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#E00072" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And here's how I declare the SeekBar:

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:thumb="@drawable/progressbar_thumb"                
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seek_bar"
                android:background="@drawable/progressbar_bg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/video_total_time"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/video_time_played" />
```

The problem is that the SeekBar height does not shrink to new height, which I'm expecting to be equal with height of the background image. Instead, I see a area filled with white space.

[image]

Do you know where does the white space come from, and how to git rid of it?

Comment: also interested in some solution :=))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by using a 9-patch instead of a Bitmap, for the `@android:id/background` item.

```
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:dither="true"
            android:src="@drawable/progressbar_backg" />
 </item>
```